# Tab completion for commands

Tags: 10.04, server, command-line

I've noticed on the Desktop version when typing commands like `sudo apt-get install mysq` I can tab complete like when resolving file paths. However in the server edition this does not happen. Is there a package I need for this, or a configuration file to make this happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's strange, maybe package [bash-completion](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/bash-completion) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Check your ~.bashrc file. Last para of mine reads as follows:

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable

# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile

# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

This is unmodified from the originally installed (desktop edition) file. Obviously if the section starting with if and ending with fi is commented out, then you won't get completion. Also check the other listed file locations of course.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to check [zsh](http://zshwiki.org/home/)

you can simply intall it with

> sudo apt-get install zsh

it's better than bash, and it has a lot of great customizations