# Aptitude in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab completion for commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5320/tab-completion-for-commands)

Aptitude command is missing from Ubuntu 10.10. I just installed it using apt-get install aptitude but it doesn't support autocompletion as it was doing in the previous version of Ubuntu. And as a relatively new user i find aptitude with autocompletion of packages names is way easier to use. So how to bring autocompletion back to aptitude on 10.10

Comment: Hm, works for me. Do you have the package 'bash-completion' installed? Do you have a file '/etc/bash_completion.d/aptitude'?

Comment: @ htroque : I have the package installed and the file is present. The solution below worked very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just install it maybe you just need to make aptitude aware of the existing packages (by an `sudo aptitude update`) and restart your terminal. You can also try : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure bash-completion`.